# How to add footer to the layout?

Tags: android, layout, footer

This is my layout.xml in which i want to add a fixed footer at the bottom of listview.Also, it's not possible for me to change my current layout.This layout contains an action bar at the top.The very first relative layout contains all layout including action bar relative layout to below of which i have a frame layout containing listview.I want this listview to have a footer fixed at the bottom containing some image buttons.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- This acts as Actionbar -->
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_background_strip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="toggleMenu"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/drawer_toggle_button" />

        <View 
            android:id="@+id/View1"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/View1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="115dp"
            android:text="Listview"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View 
            android:id="@+id/View2"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
        </ListView>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you can: create new layout for your `footer` and place it at bottom of its parent and make your `FrameLayout` to be placet above your `footer`

Use  `android:layout_above` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom` properties of your layouts...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!-- This acts as Actionbar -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/View1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="115dp"
        android:text="Listview"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">
    </ListView>
</FrameLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your way but the linear layout is transparent and listview is shown from the background of linear layout button.

Comment: Use layout_above attribute for listview & give it the id of footer linear layout.this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make a **footer.xml** like below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#5E616B"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_one"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:background="@drawable/footer_button_pressed"
        android:src="@drawable/pingicon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_two"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:background="@drawable/footer_button_pressed"
        android:src="@drawable/profile" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_three"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:background="@drawable/footer_button_pressed"
        android:src="@drawable/mycircle" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_four"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:background="@drawable/footer_button_pressed"
        android:src="@drawable/sendping" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_five"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:background="@drawable/footer_button_pressed"
        android:src="@drawable/settings" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The idea here is simple.Take a linear layout with **weightsum 1** and divide that weight to their childs.Here I have taken 5 imagebuttons and distributed .2 weight to each of them.Dont forget to set the layout orientation to vertical.

Then **include** the footer in your layout like:

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        layout="@layout/footer" />
```

Then design your **SCROLLVIEW** as:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"(IF ANY) >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
        </ListView>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1" >
    </ListView> 

<!--  Footer linear layout  -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:weightSum="5" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/filing_button_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/delete_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/reply_all_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/reply_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/forward_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```